# Ember-cli addon dev, how to differentiate addon dev from application dev

Tags: ember.js, node.js-addon

When you create an ember-cli addon, you are supposed to be able to run a dummy app.

If a component need to access it's vendor folder you access "public/" in production.
While developping the ember app that use the addon you access :

`app.options.project.nodeModulesPath + "/"+ this.name+"/vendor/"`

However, when you run the ember-cli addon server (the dummy app) you need only "vendor/".

`this.getEnv()` will return `developpement` while developping an addon, or an app using the addon.

How can I, in `index.js`, differentiate app dev from addon dev ?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we are in the `included` hook, you can check `this.isAddon()` to determine where are you now. Say if you are in the consumer ember app now, you can then invoke `path.dirname(require.resolve('ADDON_NAME/package.json'))` to get the absolute path of your ember add-on.

One thing to notice, `this.isAddon()` might not a public API (though it's stable enough, it's still not listed in API doc). If you concerned about this, you can use `this.parent.name()` to achieve the same goal, when you run with the dummy app, `this.parent.name()` always returns `dummy`.

BTW, `this.parent` is the same thing as `app.project` where `app` is the first argument of `included` hook.